# Why universal deep link doesn't work using <a> tag?

Tags: deep-linking, ios-universal-links, universal-link, android-universal-link

I've a link like [www.mydomain.com/myapp](http://www.mydomain.com/myapp) and it is able to deep link to my react native expo app correctly if opened from email or chat.
My react app redirects that link to playstore/appstore in case it is opened in desktop.

```
const MyAppRedirect = (): JSX.Element => {
const userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor;

  if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
    window.location.replace(<appstore link>);
  } else {
    window.location.replace(<playstore link>);
  }

  return null;
};

export default MyAppRedirect;
```

I have another webpage that links to this [www.mydomain.com/myapp](http://www.mydomain.com/myapp)

```
<a href="/myapp">Click here</a>
```

but when opened using Android's Chrome browser or IOS browser, it is not linking to the installed app.
I tried this too:

```
<a href="www.mydomain.com/myapp">Click here</a>
```

It still doesn't work. Is my only option using the custom scheme? Thanks

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @kenrickvaz yes, turns out if the deep link is the same domain as the page, it wont be able to link to the app correctly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47117683/deep-link-wont-work-if-opened-from-the-same-domain