# Deep links doesnt work when coming from the same website

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework, deep-linking

I've already been able to setup deep links (universal links), whenever a link to my site (https://app.example.com) is clicked, it automatically opens the app. If its from slack, messenger or another website. The problem is, if I'm inside app.example.com and I create a link to open app.example.com, it doesn't open the app.

I cant seem to find any documentation to address this problem and I'm not sure if its even allowed, but basically this is the flow that I want to achieve:

1. (inside app) Click Connect Wearable button
2. (in browser) Default browser opens wearable's login page
3. (in browser) Wearable redirects to my own site (https://app.example.com/confirmed)
4. (in browser) Inside this page is a button that says Return to App [href="https://app.example.com/"]
5. (inside app) App opens

But as mentioned, step 5 doesn't open the app even if I placed a link-button (as expected on how universal links work), it just redirects within the browser.

Any solution? I need to be able to handle android and iOS, as well as not interfere with PC browsers. If needed, I code using Ionic v6.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using any plugin for deeplink ?

Comment: @Swayangjit no, i followed this guide https://devdactic.com/setup-deep-links-capacitor/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deep link won't work if opened from the same domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47117683/deep-link-wont-work-if-opened-from-the-same-domain)

Comment: @JordinVell

Not sure if this will work in your case but I had a similar req wanting 'when in app click on deep-link of same app' and it worked with the below.

Req:
- app is open and being used by user, button is clicked from within the app which holds an app deep-link. navigate user according to deep-link url.

Achieved by below code. 
Note: It only worked when setting the "target" to *_system*.
 

window.open(${enter https deep-link here}, '_system');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is expected behavior.

The reason is,

Let's say your user actually chose to navigate to your website instead of the application. Since the user is already browsing the website, we can assume the user will keep browsing the website, otherwise, he or she would be inside the app already.

This user might navigate to different pages on your website. If deep links try to send users to the app every time, it would be a terrible UX.

If your intent is to always open the app anyways, using a custom URI scheme is the way to go.

Comment: Hi @Ajan65, could you please share any reference link if possible

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit late, but at least leave it here for other guys who are looking for the solution.

In our team, we met the same issue recently.
As @selcuk-sahin said, it is indeed the expected behavior. But there are some ways to overcome it.

**Solution 1: To use a subdomain for deep links**
If a user navigates in the same domain in the browser, https://app.example.com then neither Chrome nor Safari allows an application to intercept the request and to be opened.
But if the user navigates to https://subdomain.app.example.com then it is the change of the domain and your app will be opened if linked to that subdomain.

So just on step 5 use the new subdomain:

```
https://subdomain.app.example.com
```

There is also a recommendation about it on the official apple doc
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3155-debugging-universal-links#Use-universal-links-on-your-site

**Solution 2: Use custom URI schemes.**
For example:

```
openapp://app.example.com
```

And for example in AndroidManifest.xml subscribe to it:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

  <data
    android:scheme="openapp"
    android:host="app.example.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

**Disadvantage** of this solution is that if your app is not installed this approach will fail.

**Solution 3(only Android)**
There is also one more way, specifically for Android is to use a predefined system custom URL scheme:

```
android-app://com.example.app/
```

In you webpage you will have something like this:

```
<a href="android-app://com.example.app/
#Intent;action=com.example.CUSTOM_ACTION;end" target="_blank">Open app</a>
```

And in the app:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

  <data android:scheme="android-app" />
  <data android:host="com.example.app" />
</intent-filter>
```

Here's the official android doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#URI_ANDROID_APP_SCHEME

If you want to find out more about this topic you can check my article:
https://medium.com/@oleg7green/the-specific-case-of-app-links-on-android-ios-apps-47a0455f8892

Answer (score -1):

You can try defining custom URI scheme for your apps like "myApp://" and use that inside the button in browser.

Comment: i dont want to setup custom URLs for now, i'll consider this if there are no other answers, thanks!

Comment: Hi Jordin , I didn't say URL, but custom URI scheme. As @Ajan65 said in his answer, this should be default behavior.